# How do i add a new member with an ExpressionEngine module?

Tags: php, module, member, expressionengine

I am building an ExpressionEngine module that will need the ability to add new members to the system. The core modules don't seem to be built to be used by third party modules, which seems to leave me with two slightly hacky approaches.

The first is to use the approach that the register_member method of the Member core module uses:

```
function register_member()
{
    if ( ! class_exists('Member_register'))
    {
        require PATH_MOD.'member/mod.member_register.php';
    }

    $MR = new Member_register();

    foreach(get_object_vars($this) as $key => $value)
    {
        $MR->{$key} = $value;
    }

    $MR->register_member();
}
```

This seems to be slightly dirty as i would have to work out the proper route to the mod.member_register.php file from my custom module.

The second approach is to insert the member record directly into the database which seems worse as i would be avoiding all of the existing code for creating members. Neither of these approaches seem to be that clean, can anyone suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

> The first approach is to use the the `register_member` method of the
>   Member Module uses [...]

I would be wary of reusing or including ExpressionEngine's own Member Module functionality, since the [Freelancer License](http://expressionengine.com/overview/pricing) doesn't include any Member Management capabilities ... so requiring a file that *may not exist* isn't such a good idea.

Furthermore, EllisLab stated in the [EE 2.2 Developer Preview announcement](http://expressionengine.com/blog/entry/expressionengine_2.2_add-on_developer_preview/) that going forward they are going to be more strict on enforcing public/private/protected class vars and methods.

> The second approach is to insert the
>   member record directly into the
>   database which seems worse as i would
>   be avoiding all of the existing code
>   for creating members.

I couldn't agree more — not to mention this may circumvent many of the built-in conditional and security checks that occur when registering new users.

*On a side note, The [Solspace User Module](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/user/) offers the ability to register new members from outside the Control Panel, so the functionality has been accomplished by a Module before.*

> Neither of these approaches seem to be
>   that clean, can anyone suggest a
>   better approach?

This is a great question, and can be better answered by posting it where more ExpressionEngine Developers may see it — for example, in the [ExpressionEngine Pro Network Discussion forum](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewforum/101/) or in the [Development and Programming forum](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewforum/116/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've posted it there now. I'll update here with an answer if i get one.